# Using tinyMCE into modal window

Tags: javascript, jquery, grails, tinymce

I'm using Grails 1.3.7 and I use tinyMCE via richui. I'm trying to display a modal window which enables users to send a mail. However, if tinyMCE is correctly displayed, I can't use the text editor because of this error :

> t.win.document is null

I finally found the reason here, at the end of the article :
http://blog.mirthlab.com/2008/11/13/dynamically-adding-and-removing-tinymce-instances-to-a-page/
It seems that when I call the page with the jquery script building the modal window, DOM isn't refreshed and doesn't create the corresponding textarea.

Anyway I don't know how to resolve this, so here is my code :

Jquery code :

```
function dialogSendFirstMail(id) {
var monurl = "/myApp/emailTemplate/writeFirstMail.gsp?id_for_mail="+id;
var titre = "Premier email"
//alert(monurl);
$("#dialogSendFirstMail").load(monurl, function() {
    $(this).dialog({
        height: 'auto',
        width:'auto',
        modal: true,
        position: 'center',
        overlay: {
            backgroundColor: '#000',
            opacity: 0.5
        },
        title:titre
    });
});
}
```

GSP calling the script for the modal window :

```
<!-- ... -->
<g:if test="${params.sendFirstMail}" >
  <div id="dialogSendFirstMail"></div>
  <script>dialogSendFirstMail(${idProfil});</script>
</g:if>
</body>
```

modal window (only this for the moment) :

```
<richui:richTextEditor name="firstMail" value="%Email_de_bienvenue%"/>
```

In summary, if I detect that I have to send a first mail, the page creates a div in which is placed tinyMCE. This is what the user will see.

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned, the reason that you the the error "t.win.document is null" is because the DOM isn't refreshed. So you will have to add the tinyMCE control explicitly when you load the modal dialog. You can use something like this in the gsp which renders the richUI editor (writeFirstMail.gsp in your case) :

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    //your tinyMCE settings here 
    tinyMCE.settings = {
        mode : "textareas",
        theme : "simple",
        editor_selector : "mcesimple",
        width: 400

    };

    tinyMCE.execCommand("mceAddControl", false, "yourTextareaId");
    });
```

Once the dialog is closed, you can remove tinyMCE control from the textarea using this:

```
    tinyMCE.execCommand("mceRemoveControl", false, "yourTextareaId");
```